# Sending a lot of base64 data to PHP server

Tags: php, gif

Firstly, English is not my main language sorry for my grammer :).

**What I wanna do?**

I wanted to add a front end animated gif submission to my website. Gif also needs to be resized multiple dimensions.

**What I did?**

After realizing splitting gif to frames and resizing them is an expensive code for PHP(It's about 13 seconds to resize a 3MB 52 frames gif to 2 diffirient dimensions with imagick library); I changed my way and tried to do splitting and resizing job on the browser/client side and convert those resized frames into base64 jpegs and I succeed(frames to array buffer-array buffer to canvas-canvas to base64. Resizing a 3MB 52 frames gif to 2 dimensions taking 2-3 seconds). Now I was sending a lot of base64 data to the server.

Then first thing I look for a library to re-join those frames on server side. (re-joining frames on the server side to prevent any security vulnerabilities, re-joining them will corrupt hack codes in the frames if there is one.)

I found the GifAnim library that performs really good and updated.

All good! 13 seconds server side animated gif resizing went to into 2-3 seconds on the client and 1 second for the server side!

But I started to think "maybe it's better if I send a file object instead of base64 code for frames?" because sending 104 base64 image code to server (52 frames and 2 diffirent dimensions) looked too big for me. Also I have to base64_decode() -> imagecreatefromstring() all of those 104 base 64 image to use them as an image.

**Question:** Would it be better if I turns base64 into file object and sending file objects instead of base64 image codes to the server?
How good/stable base64_decode() function? Because decoding 100-150 images looked so unnatural to me.

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: base64 encoding a file will almost always produce a larger payload. Sending binary data, especially image data, will be pretty optimal.

Comment: Why would you send base64 data instead of a binary image file? It seems like there is no advantage.

Comment: Thank you! While I was trying to resize gif frames on client side I realized the fastest way to do it is html canvases. It's really fast way to resize them with canvas.I learnt you can not directly turn canvases into binary image file, you need to use convert base64 on each canvas and then you can turn them into file. I didn't wanted to create a new payload for the browser and also upload file count limit of PHP were preventing sending 100+ images to server its 20 by default. It's okay for me but I have client that uses my system on cheap hostings. Sending base64 data bypassing upload limit.

Comment: @techn9ne You definitely *can* get binary images out of your canvas.  And, why not have the client also create the GIF while it's at it?

Comment: It looks like it's possible ([HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)), but still a few browsers that don't support it. But yeah, if base64 -> binary is the method you choose, that would be a much better option than sending base64 data.

Comment: To send the binary data to the server, look at [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: @Cully I tried to send this data to the server before but imagecreatefromstring() function did'nt worked on it. It was like "blob:https://localhost/A141-A2525..." like data and I thought it's only avaible for the browser usage. I found this post before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800419/converting-html-canvas-to-binary-image-data in here he/she was also turning canvas to base64 (toDataURL()) firstly to get a image binary data. I will try to use toBlob method again, I hope i can do it with blobs... I will edit my question after If i can make it.

Comment: The SO answer with the `createBlob` function might be a good bet. `toBlob` still isn't supported by most mobile browsers.

Comment: Look into what @Brad mentioned too. Creating the GIF in-browser might be a good option. You wouldn't ever need to send it to the server.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Hello sir! thank you for your reply but I have no problem with sending it. I'm already using FormData.append() function on my ajax form. The problem is base64 is looks too big and what is alternative ways to do it. If there none, which is better, sending files or base64 image data.

Comment: @Cully But I need to save it to use it as a post thumbnail or etc. So I need to send it :/. Oh thank you I will check createblob to. I guess I tried it before but i don't remember why it failed. Will check it again.

Comment: @Brad hello sir! thanks for reply! Because If I let them send a fully created-resized gif on client side they can add shell codes into images. And the safest way to save images into the server is re-creating them. With this way It does'nt matters if frames contains shell codes in it. I'm already imagecreatefromstring() function on them and re-proccing all frames to prevent this vulnerability problem.

Comment: @techn9ne I think it's a bit of a stretch.  While there have been image codec vulnerabilities in the past, and there will undoubtedly be more in the future, there have been few practical attacks based on these techniques.  You could always scan the uploaded files.  In any case, I don't really know what the problem is that you're getting at this point.  Sounds like you just need to resize an animated GIF, but it isn't clear why.  And, it isn't even clear why you're using GIF.  It sounds like you have video frames... and for that, you should be using a real video codec.

Comment: @Brad I'm developing a reddit-like wordpress theme and animated gif support was a thing that I always wanted on my theme. I wanted add a secure animated gif upload way for my clients and for my theme. If I was doing it for my website only I would use video codec but I have so many clients on cheap hosting services. So I need to create a general way to do it. Recreating an image (and also checking exif, size, width, height) is the safest way to front end uploads. Making this job fully on server side is a expensive job for the CPU. With this way I'm just splitting this proc. ----

Comment: sending a lot of frames of a gif to the server and creating fully new created gif from those frames to kill bad codes. I could'nt figured out a better way to do it. If you have a better idea to make this better I'm totally open to new ideas... Because Imagick resizes a gif in 13 seconds (52 frames 3 MB) but with this way it's about 0.70 seconds to recreate a gif from frames in server side and about to 2-3 seconds to split-resize frames on the client side. I can not see a reason to don't use this way.

Comment: @techn9ne You mention you're encoding and decoding these GIFs as Base64 data "*to kill bad codes*"? Can you elaborate on how exactly this Base64 encoding/decoding scheme accomplishes that?

Comment: @esqew I never said base64 data kills the bad code. I said "I'm not fully resizing it in the client side because I have to recreate a gif from those frames on the server side to prevent bad codes in it." base64 has nothing to do against bad codes in a image... but php's imagecreatefromstring() and imgif() does.

Comment: @techn9ne Got it, thanks for the clarification. I was sure I was mistaken in my first pass through this thread